# Convert grammar to language (automata)

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Let $G$ be the grammar

$S \rightarrow aAb \ |$

$A \rightarrow cAc \ | \ B$

$B \rightarrow bSa \ | \ \epsilon$

over the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$

Decide $L(G)$ (Decide the language from grammar G).

Is there any method to follow or do I just have to resort to trying strings and finding a pattern? I find the second option extremly exhausting and prone to error.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the grammar is simple enough, and this one definitely is, you can analyze the possible derivations.

Any derivation must start with an application of the production $S\to aAb$; after that, the only productions immediately available are the two $A$ productions. The only production that can terminate a derivation is $B\to\epsilon$, so at some point we’ll have to get a $B$. However, we can apply $A\to cAc$ any number of times before we apply $A\to B$. Thus, any derivation must begin

$$S\Rightarrow aAb\Rightarrow^n ac^nAc^nb\Rightarrow ac^nBc^nb$$

for some $n\ge 0$. At this point we can apply $B\to\epsilon$ to get the word $ac^{2n}b$, or we can apply $B\to bSa$ to get $ac^nbSac^nb$. At this point we’re basically starting over, except that whatever word is generated by $S$ this time will be sandwiched between two copies of $ac^nb$.

Suppose that we go apply $B\to bSa$ $m$ times before we finally terminate the derivation with $B\to\epsilon$. If $m=0$, we simply get $ac^{2n}b$ for some $n\ge 0$. If $m\ge 1$, we have $ac^{n_1}bSac^{n_1}b$ for some $n_1\ge 0$ after the first application of $B\to bSa$. After the second we have

$$ac^{n_1}bac^{n_2}bSac^{n_2}bac^{n_1}b$$

for some $n_1,n_2\ge 0$. After the $m$-th we have

$$ac^{n_1}bac^{n_2}b\ldots ac^{n_m}bSac^{n_m}b\ldots ac^{n_2}bac^{n_1}b$$

for some $n_1,\ldots,n_m\ge 0$, and in the end we have

$$ac^{n_1}bac^{n_2}b\ldots ac^{n_m}bac^{2n_{m+1}}bac^{n_m}b\ldots ac^{n_2}bac^{n_1}b$$

for some $n_1,\ldots,n_{m+1}\ge 0$.

Comment: @darrrrUC: You’re welcome!